# “make it two weeks” meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> A: So, when is the next meeting?
>
> B: I was hoping next week, but we can make it two weeks if that's better for everybody.

This is from my meeting.

Could you let me know what "we can make it two weeks" means?

If today is January first, does it mean we can have the meetings on Jan 8th and 15th both?

I asked my friend and she said "It means if you can’t make it in one week, they can extend it to two".

So I thought it meant 8th and 15th both, since "extend it to two weeks" is what I understood,

but my another friend said it means only 15th, not 8th.

Could you explain why “make it two weeks” and “extend it to two weeks” mean only 15th?
In my understanding, I think they mean 8th and 15th both.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a unique answer. I would assume that B meant to say, 'I was hoping that we would meet on 8th Jan, but I am happy to meet on 15th Jan instead, if that is better for everybody.' I can understand that other people would think that B menat that there would be a meeting on both the 8th Jan and 15th Jan. As a general rule, It would have been better to clarify the date or dates of the next meeting before closing the previous meeting. It is always best to specify a specific date for a meeting, rather than ambiguous terms like 'next week', 'next Tuesday', etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the phrase "make it two weeks" is clear, but the actual date of the meeting cannot be certainly determined without knowing the rest of the conversation.

> A: So, when is the next meeting?
>
> B: I was hoping next week, but we can make it two weeks if that's better for everybody.

Here "make it two weeks" simply means to set the meeting for two weeks from now instead of next week. This phrasing is common when altering some previously determined fact or plan, such as "I would like a small coffee... Actually, make it a large coffee." The phrase in your context would usually be understood to indicate an alternate meeting time, *not* an additional meeting time.

However, the actual date of the meeting is not completely clear, because the person did not say "we *will* make it two weeks", but "we *can* make it two weeks *if* that's better for everybody".

Was it clear that having the meeting in two weeks would be better for everyone? If so, then the meeting is likely in two weeks. It might be a good idea to confirm the time with someone.

Comment: Thanks. Why I’m so confused is “please make the coffee a large coffee” means “the coffee= a larger one”. But in the sentence, I don’t understand how “the next meeting= two weeks” means the next meeting is two weeks later.

Comment: @MangoGummy In the coffee example, it might be more helpful to think of "it" as referring to "the order", as in, "Change the order to a large coffee." In your meeting example, "it" refers to "the time of the meeting", so "we can make it two weeks" means "we can make the time of the meeting two weeks from now". "Make it ____" is understood by native speakers as "change what we decided to something else".

Comment: Ah two weeks “from now”! With from now it’s more clear. Thanks!